# How to navigate between controls in a Window by TAB key?

Tags: c++, windows

I created a window by calling `CreateWindow`, and put 2 edit controls on it.
The edit controls had `WS_TABSTOP` style, which was enabled. I could change its text, but navigation between controls by TAB key did not work.

I put this code in my message loop:

```
MSG msg;
while ( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
{
    if ( !msg.hwnd || !IsDialogMessage( msg.hwnd, &msg ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, navigating by TAB did not work, edit controls didn't edit, and the only thing happened by pressing TAB was the selection of the text of first control. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try to post a complete, small program that illustrates the problem. The above doesn't seem to be wrong, although it is most probably unnecessary.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf For a window created with `CreateWindow` then the call to `IsDialogMessage` is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window handle you pass to IsDialogMessage is the dialog-like window you want to navigate through. You are passing the window that received the message, which is probably the edit control, not the top-level window.

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic choices: either put the controls into an actual dialog (which you'll invoke with `DialogBox` (or one of its close relatives like `DialogBoxEx`), or else handle the tabbing yourself.

In the latter case, you need to react when a `tab` is entered, and set the focus to the other control. Offhand, I don't remember whether you can handle this via `WM_NOTIFY`, or if you'll have to subclass the controls.

Comment: Raymond [says otherwise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/21/55384.aspx).